# Script to keyframe the Mapping Node Location

Tags: python, node-editor, keyframes

This line was working a couple years ago to keyframe the Mapping Node (Point) Location for X, Y, Z.

`(bpy.data.materials[self.obj_mat].node_tree.nodes["Mapping"].keyframe_insert(data_path = "translation", frame = frame_set)`

Now I get an error message:
`TypeError: bpy_struct.keyframe_insert() property "translation" not found`

Seems somewhere in time an update apparently changed the "translation" data_path on the Mapping node and so if someone can help me out on this by telling me the new data_path and how to find out the data paths - as just copying the data path gives the following:

`bpy.data.materials["Mat.002"].node_tree.nodes["Mapping"].inputs[1].default_value[1]`

and not sure how `inputs[1].default_value[1]` let's me know what to put in. I checked the Actions and see "X Default Value (Location)", which was another dead-end.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the attributes that used to be under separate attrs like `translation, rotation, scale` are now collected under a attr called `inputs` with indices pointing to each one.

```
import bpy

D = bpy.data

mapping_node = D.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes["Mapping"]

for inp in mapping_node.inputs:
    print(f"Input: {inp}")
    print(f"Input Name: {inp.name}")

>>>
Input: <bpy_struct, NodeSocketVector("Vector") at 0x00000167BB142C08>
Input Name: Vector
Input: <bpy_struct, NodeSocketVectorTranslation("Location") at 0x00000167BB142808>
Input Name: Location
Input: <bpy_struct, NodeSocketVectorEuler("Rotation") at 0x00000167BB142608>
Input Name: Rotation
Input: <bpy_struct, NodeSocketVectorXYZ("Scale") at 0x00000167BB141208>
Input Name: Scale
```

You can also access each value by name:

```
print(mapping_node.inputs['Location'])
>>> <bpy_struct, NodeSocketVectorTranslation("Location") at 0x00000167BB142808>
```

So you can either access them by their index, starting at 0, or you can access them by name. Then you set the keyframe on the value directly.

`mapping_node.inputs['Location'].keyframe_insert("default_value", frame=21)`

I was able to find all this out by copying the data path of and then pasting it into the python console under the script editing window. This allows you to back up step-by-step and inspect the values of each attribute one by one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info Jakemoyo!  Worked well.

Comment: Awesome can you accept the answer?